# Select from MySQL with jQuery without refresh and populate <li>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have table in mysql which stores 'number' (which can be used to identify li) and 'path' (path to image in folder on server) columns.

I have PHP function which pulls data from table to array:

```
function GetPaths() {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","****");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pictures");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$rows[] = $row;
// i can echo $rows['number'] and $rows['path']
}
print json_encode($rows);
}
```

Now, my problem is I don't know that much Javascript. What is the best approach to run this function from javascript to update paths to images? I should mention that column 'Path' can have default value which is path to default image "default.png" and some other value which user inputs in database.

Basicaly what I need to do is: I need to populate list with images based on list item id's which is bound to `$rows['number']` (i have 35 rows with values 1,2,3,4...35 and 35 list items with same id's) but with some check so I don't refresh images which have same path already set. And i need to do all of that without refreshing page with some timer. 
This is where i need to put $row['path']:
    `<ul>
    <li id=1></li>
    <li id=2></li>
    <li id=3></li>
    ...
    <li id=35></li>
    </ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parts in your problem.
First, you need to understand that JavaScript can't access PHP functions directly, it can only make HTTP requests and load the response. Therefore, you need to add a function call to your PHP file (`GetPaths();` after the last line should suffice).

Second, the JQuery side. I am going to add some HTML to clarify things.

```
<ul>
   <li id="img_1" class="image" ></li>
   <li id="img_2" class="image"></li>
    ...
   <li id="img_35" class="image"></li>
</ul>
var refreshImages = function() {
    $.get( // JQuery function to execute an AJAX Get request
        url: "url_to_php_file",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
           data.forEach(function(src, i) {
               var img_tag = $("#img_+i).find("img"); // Finds the correct img tag to update
               if(img_tag.attr('src') != src) {
                   img_tag.attr('src', src);
               }
           }
        }
}

window.setInterval(refreshImages, 1000); // Calls refreshImages every 1000ms
```

Comment: Excuse me, am I doing something wrong here? I have modified your javascript a little bit and it's not working, then i run php directly to see what is returned and it goes something like this: `{"0":"1","number":"1","1":"blue.png","path":"blue.png"},{"0":"2","number":"2","1":"red.png","path":"red.png"},{"0":"3","number":"3","1":"green.png","path":"green.png"}`

Do I need to parse this data aditionaly in javascript?

Comment: This return is not valid json. It should be something like:
`{"0":{"0":"1","number":"1","1":"blue.png","path":"blue.png"},"1":{"0":"2","number":"2","‌​1":"red.png","path":"red.png"},"3":{"0":"3","number":"3","1":"green.png","path":"gree‌n.png"}}`

Then you'll need to modify the JS since you're having an array of arrays, not an array of strings. It should be a trivial change though.

Comment: Managed to make it work by:
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM currdraw");
foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('number'=>$row['number'],
                    'path'=>$row['path']);
}
$dbh = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);

Answer (score 0):

Use Asynchronus javascript(Ajax) to make request to server without refershing page. You can use jquery to make Ajax Get and Post Request.

Please have a look on it to make ajax post request using jquery library 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

please have look in it to make ajax get request using jquery library 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/